# PL/SQL Trying to execute a very simple procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I know this is a very stupid question, but I just can't get this to work. I get an error saying that identifier hello must be declared

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE hello (p_name IN VARCHAR2) 
IS
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line (‘Welcome '|| p_name);
END hello;
/

EXECUTE hello('JOHN');
```

Comment: Use `'` instead of `‘`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything's fine, except the first single quote in DBMS_OUTPUT call:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE hello (p_name IN VARCHAR2)
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4  dbms_output.put_line ('Welcome '|| p_name);
  5  END hello;        --  ^ change this one
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> EXECUTE hello('JOHN');
Welcome JOHN

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```